# Azure storage emulator is not starting

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

I am using azure storage emulator version 5.2 but unable to start it after AzureStorageEmulator.exe start command. I got Error: Unable to start the storage emulator. I am getting "access denied" any ideas?

Comment: Did you change something with your SQL install? The emulator uses that under the hood. Try re-initializing the storage emulator running `AzureStorageEmulator.exe init`. This should "Initialize the emulator database and configuration"

Comment: after running init command i got "Initialization successful. The storage emulator is now ready for use.
The storage emulator was successfully initialized and is ready to use."..but it isn't solving issue..still unable to start emulator.

Comment: Any other messages? Or entries in the EventLog?

Comment: no other messages.

Comment: hey, i used -inprocess after start and i got access denied, unable to start AzureStorageEmulator

Comment: Are you running it as Administrator?

Comment: it is working now..I just reinstalled it and restarted it and problem resolved..thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

In the file of AzureStorageEmulator.exe runs cmd as administrator, type AzureStorageEmulator.exe **init**, then type AzureStorageEmulator.exe **start**.